# MissingPluginException, for flutter sound

Tags: flutter

MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method stop on channel xyz.luan/audioplayers))
This error shown while i tried to play sound in flutter
Any help here!!

Comment: try restarting the application instead of hot reload or hot restart

Comment: I rerun the application using run>start debugging but still the result is same. It works perfectly until i pressed button to play a sound

Answer (score 0):

Try remove app ,then install it again;
**That's work for me**

Comment: I rerun the application using run>start debugging but still the result is same.
It works perfectly until i pressed button to play a sound